# UIStackView and ViewWithTag

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

i am trying to add a UIbutton to a specific StackView.

what i have come up with is

```
viewWithTag(2)?.addSubview(button)
```

is it wrong to implement it this way? or is there any better way to implement it?

Comment: Don't use view with tag. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't do that instead you should create `@IBoutlet`'s for the `views` and then use those to add the `button` as a `subView`. I only use the `tag` property when i'm adding `Views` from an `Extension` but I set the `tag` as `NSIntegerMax` so it's easy to check if it already exits. You should really use `@IBoutlets` unless you have no other choice.